# What should my automated git update process look like?

Tags: git, git-workflow

I come from a subversion background and recently my company made the switch to git. I used to have a cron entry, on my laptop, to update the multitude of checkouts, on a nightly basis. This way, I would be running against current versions of the different components of our system; especially the parts that I wasn't actively developing, but had dependencies on. I would like to achieve the same thing with git.

Here's my old update process with svn:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
checkout="$1"
svn update --accept postpone ${checkout}
# Run a script to report conflicts that I would resolve in the morning.
```

I've read a lot of blogs posts on the topic and asked around, and I haven't found many consistent answers. Also, none of the solutions I've seen so far are complete to the extent that I am looking for.  I've taken all those opinions and created the script below.

**How should I deal with submodules?**

**Are there situations, or gotchas, I have not accounted for?**

```
#!/bin/bash -e
checkout="$1"
now=$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S)
cd ${checkout}

# If you are in the middle of a rebase, merge, bisect, or cherry pick, then don't update.
if [ -e .git/rebase-merge ]; then continue; fi
if [ -e .git/MERGE_HEAD ]; then continue; fi
if [ -e .git/BISECT_LOG ]; then continue; fi
if [ -e .git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD ]; then continue; fi

# Determine what branch the project is on, if any.
ref=$(git branch | grep '^*' | sed 's/^* //')

if [[ $ref = "(no branch)" ]]; then
  # The directory is in a headless state.
  ref=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
fi

# If there are any uncommitted changes, stash them.
stashed=false
if [[ $(git status --ignore-submodules --porcelain | grep -v '^??') != "" ]]; then
    stashed=true
    git stash save "auto-${now}"
fi

# If there are any untracked files, add and stash them.
untracked=false
if [[ $(git status --ignore-submodules --porcelain) != "" ]]; then
    untracked=true
    git add .
    git stash save "auto-untracked-${now}"
fi

# If status is non-empty, at this point, something is very wrong, fail.
if [[ $(git status --ignore-submodules --porcelain) != "" ]]; then continue; fi

# If not on master, checkout master.
if [[ $ref != "master" ]]; then
    git checkout master
fi

# Rebase upstream changes.
git pull --rebase

# Restore branch, if necessary.
if [[ $ref != "master" ]]; then
    git checkout ${ref}
fi

# Restore untracked files, unless there is a conflict.
if $untracked; then
    stash_name=$(git stash list | grep ": auto-untracked-${now}\$" | sed "s/^\([^:]*\):.*$/\\1/")
    git stash pop ${stash_name}
    git reset HEAD .
fi

# Restore uncommitted changes, unless there is a conflict.
if $stashed; then
    stash_name=$(git stash list | grep ": auto-${now}\$" | sed "s/^\([^:]*\):.*$/\\1/")
    git stash pop ${stash_name}
fi

# Update submodules.
git submodule init
git submodule update --recursive
```

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to use ``git symbolic-ref`` instead of ``git branch`` for getting the current branch name. ``git branch`` is 'porcelain' - its output is meant for human consumption, while ``git symbolic-ref`` is 'plumbing' - its output is meant for other scripts' consumption.

Comment: Initially I did use `git symbolic-ref`, but switched to `git branch` because it returns an exit code of 1, when the code was in a detached head state. I suppose I could switch it to `set -o pipefail; ref=$((git symbolic-ref -q HEAD | sed -e 's/refs\/heads\///') || git rev-parse HEAD)`

Comment: Interesting approach - spend every morning resolving merge conflicts. Good idea to keep your repos up to date with the remote but it could be disruptive if you are in the middle of something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there are changes in the submodules as well. See `git submodule foreach`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Are you saying that I should do the same pre-pull steps on all of the submodules, before the pull? Similarly, with the post-pull steps.

Comment: You should ensure there are no changes is the submodules, fetch in them. Then at the top level do the update --recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had duplicate submodule request in my .gitmodules file.